# screen scape node.js with authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, screen-scraping

Im trying to screen scape a site with authentication in node.js, but when i try to submit the form i get this:

"Your browser "for others" does not support our site."

The username gets set, but the password seems to be blank.

im using the request node module.

My code:

```
router.get('/scrape', function(req, respond){

    var credentials = {
        username: 'kevin',
        password: 'secret'
    };

    request.post({
        uri: my site url here,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials)
    }, function(err, res, body){
        if(err) {
            respond.end(err);
        }

        respond.send(body);

    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably u need to specify User-Agent header, like :

```
var credentials = {
    username: 'kevin',
    password: 'secret'
};

request.post({
    uri: my site url here,
    headers: { 
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36'
    },
    form:credentials
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        respond.end(err);
    }

    respond.send(body);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. The password field is still empty but that another problem :-)

Comment: you're welcome , recently I was scraping a page, I was getting error pages , so i looked at the headers that send my browser so I read about User-agent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)